# Add external users to Sharepoint online site collection without sending invitations

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, office

Can we add external users to Sharepoint online site collection without sending invitations?  I dont want to enable anonymous access and B2B

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using CSOM you can invite external users without sending them an invitation. However, users will only get access to SharePoint after authenticating with a Microsoft or AAD account and accepting the invitation link. As far as I know you can't just give them access.

I know there's a process where you could do so with B2B, but don't know exactly how that works.